# Sidekiq 3.4.2 and Rails 4.2.0 having error with 'undefined method perform_at'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, ruby-2.2

I have jobs class for ex

```
class TempJob < ActiveJob::Base
    queue_as :default # To Do Design Queue

    around_perform do |job, block|
        puts "Before Perform'

        block.call

        puts "After Perform"
    end

    def perform(*args)
        puts "Job Start"
    end
end
```

I am trying to schedule job to be execute 1hours from now

```
TempJob.perform_at(1.hour.from_now)
```

but it is giving me following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `perform_at' for TempJob:Class
```

Using Rails 4.2.0, Ruby 2.2.0, and Sidekiq 3.4.2.

Comment: Please don't add your setup details at the top of the question, I already moved them to the bottom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`perform_at` is the name of the method provided by Sidekiq, not ActiveJob. If you want to schedule a job to run at a relative time using ActiveJob, you should use the [ActiveJob's set](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Core/ClassMethods.html#method-i-set) method like this:

```
TempJob.set(wait: 1.hour).perform_later
```

Also take a look at the [ActiveJob basics guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job).